# Can't SSH Tunnel out of Docker container

Tags: python, docker, ssh

I have the following setup:

`main.py`:

```
import os
import io
import logging
import sshtunnel
import paramiko
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")

tunnel = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (os.environ.get("SSH_HOST"), 22),
    ssh_username=os.environ.get("SSH_USER"),
    ssh_pkey=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(
        io.StringIO(os.environ.get("SSH_PKEY")),
    ),
    remote_bind_addresses=[("0.0.0.0", 5432)],
    logger=logger,
)

try:
    tunnel.start()
    print("SSH Tunnel successful")
except sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError as e:
    print("SSH Tunnel failed")
    print(e)
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
sshtunnel==0.4.0
paramiko==3.2.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11.7-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y openssh-client

RUN python3 -m venv venv

RUN . venv/bin/activate

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY ./main.py ./main.py

COPY ./.env ./.env

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

If we build the image and start the container with the following command: "docker run --network=host test" the app in the container will throw the exception as it is not able to establish the SSH connection. It says that the authentication with the publickey failed.

I started the application without the container and the SSH connection was established and no exception was thrown. I also started a shell in the container and tried to establish the connection with ssh -vvv and it failed at the publickey authentication as well and asked for a password for the host.

Comment: How are you providing the ssh key material?  It's not in your Dockerfile (and this is good) but you should have a `docker run -v` option to push it into the container, and it looks like you need to have _e.g._ `docker run -e SSH_PKEY=...` options to set the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH credentials are coming from environment variables. I see that you are baking a `.env` file into the image. This might not be the best idea, but let's get it working. The content of `.env` might look like this:

```
SSH_HOST=18.170.47.152
SSH_USER=ubuntu
SSH_PKEY="-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Don't worry, the SSH private key is bogus!

That should do the job. I have tested with my genuine credentials and a SSH server on AWS (see screenshot below).

Better ways to share the credentials might be:

1. to pass them to `docker run` using the `-e` argument or
2. to volume mount the `.env` file using `-v` rather than baking it into the image itself, which is a lot less flexible!

A good option might be to use something like:

```bash
docker run -it -e SSH_PKEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" <image name>
```

That will grab the contents of the SSH private key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and send it through as an environment variable to the container. This works well because the private key is a chunky piece of data and you wouldn't want it being explicitly included in your shell history.

[image]